Custom material theme has no --mat and --mdc color variables set
i've updated my project from Angular material 2 to Angular material 3 with the last update (18.2.1) why all variables of components aren't set? the theme class is generated by "ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme" all components (like buttons) has no color.
And after that, there is a way to get the option "default-contrast" while getting the color from the palette?
thanks!
I've found that adding
:root {
    @include mat.core();
    @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
    @include mat.system-level-colors($light-theme);
    @include mat.system-level-typography($light-theme);
    ...
}

resolve the problem but i dont know why and if it's the correct solution.

1. Colors not available
All color variants are no more available by default with angular material v3.
See documentation:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-component-color-variants

Using component color variants
A number of components have a color input property that allows
developers to apply different color variants of the component. When
using an M3 theme, this input still adds a CSS class to the component
(e.g. .mat-accent). However, there are no built-in styles targeting
these classes. You can instead apply color variants by passing the
$color-variant option to a component's -theme or -color mixins.
This API is more flexible, and produces less CSS. For example, the
.tertiary-checkbox class shown above can be applied to any checkbox or
any element that contains checkboxes, to change the color of all
checkboxes within that element.
While you should prefer applying the mixins with color variants
explicitly, if migrating from M2 to M3 you can alternatively use the
provided backwards compatibility mixins that apply styles directly to
the existing CSS classes (mat-primary, mat-accent, and mat-warn).

With v3 theme, you're supposed to create and use classes to apply style, instead of directly using color="accent" / color="primary" on material components.
In html:
 <mat-checkbox class="tertiary-checkbox" />
 <section class="tertiary-checkbox">
   <mat-checkbox />
 </section>

In scss/sass:
 @use '@angular/material' as mat;

 $theme: mat.define-theme();
 
 .tertiary-checkbox {
   @include mat.checkbox-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
 }

You can check the documentation to see the default color variant, and other available $color-variant for each material component.
This may help you too: https://material.angular.io/guide/material-2-theming#how-to-migrate-an-app-from-material-2-to-material-3
2. Access color contrast
With material 3, there are now color roles that can be used. Colors can be retrieved from m3 theme with these role names. Contrast color roles are the ones beggining with "on-".
https://m3.material.io/styles/color/roles
https://m3.material.io/styles/color/system/how-the-system-works#3ce9da92-a118-4692-8b2c-c5c52a413fa6
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-color-roles
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
$primary: mat.get-theme-color($m3-theme, primary); //primary role
// associated contrast of primary role
$primary-contrast: mat.get-theme-color($m3-theme, on-primary); 


I think the main fix was using all-component-themes which applies all the sub themes designed for each component.
This is the source code of all-component-themes($theme), which is just a wrapper function that imports the individual themes.
Maybe you are using --use-system-variable: true which is causing the system variables to not be present and causing the color not to be set properly.
So we have to import them manually using mat.system-level-colors and mat.system-level-typography.

I confirmed with a stackblitz and this is a good workaround for the --use-system-variables: true bug, which does not apply the colors.
:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($budgetify-theme);
  @include mat.system-level-colors(
    $budgetify-theme
  ); // <- workaround for use system variables bug
  @include mat.system-level-typography(
    $budgetify-theme
  ); // <- workaround for use system variables bug
}

Stackblitz Demo
Related answer - Colors are not visible for the Angular Custom Material theme in Angular 18
